# Grouped tables just for layout in IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitableview

I'm new to Interface Builder and Objective-C. 
I'd like to layout an iPhone interace in IB similar to the "edit event" or "edit contact" in the native iPhone apps where Grouped Tables are used.
It seems like i have to add several very generic-looking Grouped Tables in IB, and then write a bunch of -cellForRowAtIndexPath: and numberOf RowsInSection for each grouped table.
... Which just seems really 'wrong' when all i want to do is put a label and a textField in a slightly nicer layout.

so am i missing the point somewhere?  Or do i really need to write a bunch of delegate classes just to layout the UI in groupedTables?

thanks,
richard

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an IB way to get that look yourself without using what you've said, unless maybe you wanted just a single cell rounded corner look without doing it through images, your own UIView, etc.. Then you can possibly use the UIButton (playing with some of its settings like user interaction or selection color) and put your own UILabels/UIViews in there.

Also, just to correct your statement, you don't need multiple grouped tables. You would have one UITableView that has the grouped style and multiple sections. For your case, you would only have 1 section and 1 row.